# Adding a custom field to Django Mezzanine blog post

Tags: django, python-3.x, mezzanine

Starting from a vanilla mezzanine application, I can't seem to add a caption to the blog post model.

Reference URL instructions: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-customization.html

In settings.py:

```
EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
  (
    "mezzanine.pages.models.BlogPost.caption",
    "CharField",
    ("Caption",),
    {"blank": True, 'max_length': 150},
  ),
)
```

From this point, running *python ./manage.py makemigrations*

returns *No changes detected*

So, I decided to try and create an app called UpdateBlogPost in Django

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost

class BlogPost(BlogPost):
    caption           = models.CharField("Caption", max_length=200)
    tags              = models.CharField("Tags", max_length=100)
    featured_position = models.IntegerField("Featured Position", default=0, null=True)
```

Running makemigrations on the above produces a migration, but perhaps experienced Django developers will already realize that it produces OneToOneField migration to relate UpdateBlogPost.BlogPost to the Mezzanine model.

A broader, more useful question to be answered would be: How do I modify/extend a model from a 3rd party library from within one of my own django apps? Also, where is the code below supposed to go, after the above succeeds? It is currently sitting in my UpdateBlogPost application's admin.py.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.blog.admin import BlogPostAdmin
from mezzanine.blog.models import BlogPost

blog_fieldsets = deepcopy(BlogPostAdmin.fieldsets)
blog_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(1, "caption")

class MyBlogPostAdmin(BlogPostAdmin):
    fieldsets = blog_fieldsets

admin.site.unregister(BlogPost)
admin.site.register(BlogPost, MyBlogPostAdmin)
```

Help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone comes into similar issues,

```
EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
  (
    "mezzanine.pages.models.BlogPost.caption",
    "CharField",
    ("Caption",),
    {"blank": True, 'max_length': 150},
  ),
)
```

is erroneous, and should be

```
EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
  (
    "mezzanine.blog.models.BlogPost.caption",
    "django.db.models.CharField",
    ("Caption",),
    {"default": 'Some String', 'max_length': 150},
  ),
)
```

Running *makemigrations* from there generates it as expected.

Comment: This wasn't your problem, but mine was that I had added `MIGRATION_MODULES = {"blog": "blog_migrations"}` and it wouldn't make the migrations. I had to explicitly run `./manage.py makemigrations blog` to get the migrations to recreate in my new directory. I also realized I needed to do the explicit run before adding my custom field and again after so that I would have two migrations. If you don't do that, there will be nothing to migrate as it assumes the first migration is complete.